# GWT Maven and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, project, maven, sample

A plea for help! Can anyone share a simple GWT2.0 project that uses the gwt-maven-plugin with Eclipse and demonstrates some simple RPC server calls. I've tried to follow examples, use archetypes, read badly documented websites, and follow threads on stackoverflow but all to no avail. I simply cannot get RPC to work.

I'm going to give up on maven if I can't get a simple working example and use GWT's Eclipse plugin with ant I guess. The gwt-maven-plugin archetype is too simple and does not demonstrate rpc. I've tried to extend it but cannot get it to work.

So - if anyone can help I'd be very grateful. I don't even have a specific question to ask as there are so many moving parts and so little documentation. I need a working example project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the [simpleworklog](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simpleworklog/) project might be what you are looking for (a rather complex project that uses GWT + Maven + RPC). Source code available via:

```
svn co https://simpleworklog.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/simpleworklog simpleworklog
```

There's also the [gwt-maven2-starter-app](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-maven2-starter-app/), although it seems a bit outdated.

Answer (score 3):

Another open source project using GWT 2.0 + Maven + RPC is the Apache James [hupa](http://james.apache.org/hupa/) project. You can find the source here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/james/hupa/. It uses a nested pom module structure with separate modules for client/shared/server projects. And therefor is somewhat complexer than simpleworklog mentioned by Igor, but might be a good starting point to get ideas for your build structure when creating a large GWT project.

Answer (score 0):

Apache CXF contains a log browser demo based on gwt+maven.